# NodeJS don't change database

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, pm2

I am working with NodeJS now and I have two databases (test and production).

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const Databases = {
    TestDB: new Pool({
        user: '',
        host: '',
        database: 'DEV-TEST',
        password: '',
        port: 5432,
    }),
    ProductionDB: new Pool({
        user: '',
        host: '',
        database: 'PROD',
        password: '',
        port: 5432,
    })
};

// const pool = Databases.TestDB;
const pool = Databases.ProductionDB;

pool.connect();
```

On PC it works well, but when I upload this to server an let run it with PM2 - NodeJs connects to testDB, not to Prod.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you certain that you have pushed the correct code to the server and you have killed the process and started it fresh?

If the test DB connection details are commented out I cannot see how Node would be picking them up...

Comment: yes, a restarted and recreated processes on the server - nothing changed. i also cleared cache

Comment: What if you remove the object altogether and just create a Pool with the production DB credentials?
If you remove the test DB credentials and it still connects to that server you can be certain it is looking at the wrong code...

Comment: nope, it didn't helped. I don't know where I should look. This is the only one file with db connection

Comment: it works fine on localhost, but the same code doesn't work on server

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. In console I had to type `pm2 update`.
I don't know why, but this helped me. Because I used restarts and cache cleans.